# Take user to a specific view when he/she taps on a push notification using SwiftUI App lifecycle

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There are many articles regarding how to take user to a specific view when he/she taps on a push notification using App Delegate. But is it possible to do this using only the SwiftUI App Lifecycle?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to make an attempt and then show your code as an example.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't away using only SwiftUI.  You will have to use the `AppDelegate` to respond to notifications.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("Notification received with identifier \(notification.request.identifier)")
        completionHandler([.banner, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // do what you want here
    }
}
```